# Confusing result from counting page fault in linux

Tags: linux, kernel, virtual-memory

I was writing programs to count the time of page faults in a linux system. More precisely, the time kernel execute the function `__do_page_fault`.
And somehow I wrote two global variables, named `pfcount_at_beg` and `pfcount_at_end`, which increase once when the function `__do_page_fault` is executed at different locations of the function.

To illustrate, the modified function goes as:

```c
unsigned long pfcount_at_beg = 0;
unsigned long pfcount_at_end = 0;
static void __kprobes
__do_page_fault(...)
{
    struct vm_area_sruct *vma;
    ...    // VARIABLES DEFINITION 
    unsigned int flags = FAULT_FLAG_ALLOW_RETRY | FAULT_FLAG_KILLABLE;   
    pfcount_at_beg++;        // I add THIS
    ...
    ... 
    // ORIGINAL CODE OF THE FUNCTION
    ...
    pfcount_at_end++;        // I add THIS
}
```

I expected that the value of pfcount_at_end is smaller than the value of pfcount_at_beg.

Because, I think, every time kernel executes the instructions of code `pfcount_at_end++`, it must have executed `pfcount_at_beg++`(Every function starts at the very beginning of the code).
On the other hand, as there are many conditional `return` between these two lines of code.

However, the result turns out oppositely. The value of `pfcount_at_end` is larger than the value of `pfcount_at_beg`.
I use `printk` to print these kernel variables through a self-defined `syscall`. And I wrote the user level program to call the `system call`.

Here is my simple `syscall` and user-level program:

```c
// syscall
asmlinkage int sys_mysyscall(void)
{
    printk( KERN_INFO "total pf_at_beg%lu\ntotal pf_at_end%lu\n", pfcount_at_beg, pfcount_at_end)
    return 0;
}

// user-level program
#include<linux/unistd.h>
#include<sys/syscall.h>
#define __NR_mysyscall 223
int main()
{
    syscall(__NR_mysyscall);
    return 0;
}
```

Is there anybody who knows what exactly happened during this?

Just now I modified the code, to make `pfcount_at_beg` and `pfcount_at_end` `static`. However the result did not change, i.e. the value of `pfcount_at_end` is larger than the value of `pfcount_at_beg`.
So possibly it might be caused by in-atomic operation of increment. Would it be better if I use read-write lock?

Comment: I think that the most likely possibility here is that you have a bug in your `syscall` or user level program and that you are getting the variables mixed up there. Although one other thing to consider is whether you are accessing the two variables atomically and, if not, whether there is likely to be page faults in the interim.

Comment: @Graeme I added my `syscall` program and user level program in the question. They are relatively simple because it was a exercise for experiencing how `syscall` is implemented.

Comment: Is this the real syscall code?  The printk is missing the actual values to print.

Answer (score 1):

The `++` operator is not garanteed to be atomic, so your counters may suffer concurrent access and have incorrect values. You should protect your increment as a critical section, or use the `atomic_t` type defined in `<asm/atomic.h>`, and its related `atomic_set()` and `atomic_add()` functions (and a lot more).

Not directly connected to your issue, but using a specific syscall is overkill (but maybe it is an exercise). A lighter solution could be to use a `/proc` entry (also an interesting exercise).